# Arduino Ethernet shield: dhcpaddressprinter error

Tags: arduino

I am new to the Ethernet [shield](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoShields), and I tried to used the DhcpAddressPrinter example given. But I can't get the program running correctly.

Below is the sketch:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

// Enter a MAC address for your controller below.
// Newer Ethernet shields have a MAC address printed on a sticker on the shield
byte mac[] = { 0x00, 0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0xDE, 0x02 };

// Initialize the Ethernet client library
// with the IP address and port of the server
// that you want to connect to (port 80 is default for HTTP):
EthernetClient client;

void setup() {
    // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
    Serial.begin(9600);

    // This check is only needed on the Leonardo:
    while (!Serial) {
    ; // Wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only.
}

// Start the Ethernet connection:
if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
    Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");

    // No point in carrying on, so do nothing forevermore:
    for(;;)
        ;
    }

    // Print your local IP address:
    Serial.print("My IP address: ");
    for (byte thisByte = 0; thisByte < 4; thisByte++) {
        // print the value of each byte of the IP address:
        Serial.print(Ethernet.localIP()[thisByte], DEC);
        Serial.print(".");
    }
    Serial.println();
}

void loop() {

}
```

And after I open the serial monitor, I got the message "Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP" after a long period of time.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your network does not have [DHCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol) configured. This is usually set up on the router for most home networks.

Try giving the Ardunio a static [IP address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) like so

```
byte MAC_address[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
IPAddress ipAddress(192,168,1,1152); 
EthernetClient client;
Ethernet.begin(MAC_address, ipAddress);
```

If that doesn't work how are you connecting your Arduino? Is it to a computer, a router, or a modem?